# Add js file in .info theme file. And set it to load first

Tags: javascript, .info

I added this line in my-theme.info

```
scripts[] = js/my-file.js
```

The files is loads but in last place. I need it to be loaded before all modules js files.

How can I set the weight?

I also tried (same results) in template.php with:

```
function MY-THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

  $file =  path_to_theme() . '/js/my-file.js';
  $options = array('weight' => -1000);

  drupal_add_js($file, $options);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the scope (header/footer) where to load the JS and also add a weight.

Example options:

```
$options = array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'header', 'weight' => 5));
```

Play around with these to get the file loaded on the right position that suits your needs. For more detailed information check the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7).

Comment: To add to this, the 'scope', 'even_page' and 'group' options are considered before weight, so your options should place the js in the 'header' and JS_LIBRARY in addition to a negative weight `$options = array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'header', 'group' => JS_LIBRARY, 'every_page' => TRUE, 'weight' => -999)`